# Как пропустить необходимые символы в textBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, как пропустить символы дроби и точки?

В примере проверяется `textBox1`на наличие цифр, если их нет, должна появиться ошибка. Но такой код не дает использовать символ дроби и точки...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int result;
    if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text.Trim(), out result))
    {
        // Числовые значения в формате 192.168.0.0/24 (разрешены точки, и знак дроби)
    }
    else MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте с помощью функции Replace заменить точки и слеши на, например, пробелы, и дальше уже работать с этой строкой

Comment: Либо Replace - ом замените слеш на точку, и в Trim() передавайте точку, то есть Trim('.')

Comment: Вы сами то понимание, что ваш код делает? Особенно в этом месте? `int.TryParse`

Comment: если вы хотите проверить вашу строку на то, что в ней ip или домен, то лучше воспользоваться регулярными выражениями. Напишите конкретно, для чего вам нужно проверять вхождение символов... Напишите 4 варианта строк(желательно охватить весь логический смысл), которые должны пройти через проверку

Comment: Шаблон цифр и символов: `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx` это должен быть любой IP адрес из интернета, с маской подсети от 0 до 32 https://www.pawprint.net/designresources/netmask-converter.php (если в `textBox1` допустить ошибку, например символ пробела или буква, то эти символы преобразуются в `hex` формат, что приведет к ошибке уже внутри реестра)

Comment: @tym32167 немного понял Ваш вопрос, думаю в моем случае придется использовать тип `byte result;` который будет определять число от 0 до 255, но потребуется каким-то образом отделять точки, а в конце использовать шаблон от 0 до 32 с разделителем `/`

Comment: Вы валидируете ip адрес каким то экзотическим способом. Просто загуглите валидацию ip адреса, в вашем случае, скорее всего регулярным выражением, и не занимайтесь ерундой

Answer (score 0):

Помог с решением, автор *bloomder* (за подсказки спасибо *Амир Закиров*)

```
if (int.TryParse(textBoxIPm1.Text.Replace("  ", "") // В кавычках 2 пробела (определяет 1)
                                 .Replace(".", "")
                                 .Replace("/", ""), out result))
```